# Spring security problem: Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Security to authenticate my application, but I'm getting this error when I tried to login.

```
Hibernate: select users0_.id_user as id_user1_5_, users0_.email as email2_5_, users0_.first_name as first_na3_5_, users0_.last_name as last_nam4_5_, users0_.password as password5_5_, users0_.rol as rol6_5_ from users users0_ where users0_.email=?
Hibernate: select employee0_.id_employee as id_emplo1_1_0_, employee0_.hire_date as hire_dat2_1_0_, users1_.id_user as id_user1_5_1_, users1_.email as email2_5_1_, users1_.first_name as first_na3_5_1_, users1_.last_name as last_nam4_5_1_, users1_.password as password5_5_1_, users1_.rol as rol6_5_1_ from employee employee0_ left outer join users users1_ on employee0_.id_employee=users1_.id_user where employee0_.id_employee=?
2020-02-03 13:00:47.222  WARN 66020 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

My code is:

This is the class where I have the functions related to security.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.sample.util;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.sample.negocio.services.UserService;

/**
 * Manages project security
 * @author csar
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Desde donde consultamos a la base de datos
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    UserService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/app/login").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/app/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/home");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        /*PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
                builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser("pepe@gmail.com")
                        .password(encoder.encode("1234"))
                        .roles("USER");*/

                builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bcrypt);
       /* builder
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select email as username, password as password, rol as enabled from users WHERE id_user=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT ? as username, 'USER' as ROLE")
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());*/
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity security) {
        security.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }
}
```

This is the class where I have the service, and all the functions.

**UserService.java**

```
package com.sample.negocio.services;




import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sample.modelo.Users;
import com.sample.negocio.repository.UserRepository;


/**
 * Clase para definir los servicios de User
 * @author vcanizar
 *
 */
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    //Metodo que asigna el repositorio UserRepository en el servicio UserService
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Servicio que devuelve una lista de Usuarios
     * @return
     */
    public List<Users> findAll(){
        return this.userRepository.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * MÃ©todo para realizar la operaciÃ³n de guardar un User
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    public Users create(Users user) {
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    /**
     * MÃ©todo para realizar la operaciÃ³n de actualizar un User
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    @Transactional
    public Users update(Users user) {
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }

    /**
     * MÃ©todo para realizar la operaciÃ³n de borrar un Employee
     * @param user
     */
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Users user) {
         this.userRepository.delete(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Users findByIdUser(String idUser) {
        return this.userRepository.findByIdUser(idUser);
    }

    /**
     * MÃ©todo para consultar un user por su email
     * @param iduser
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {


        Users user= userRepository.findByEmail(email);



        //Creamos un arraylist a partir de una lista de roles que vamos a introducir en los detalles de usuario
        List<GrantedAuthority> listaRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        listaRoles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userRepository));

        //Creamos un UserDetails a partir de los datos recopilados del usuario
        UserDetails userDet = new User(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(),listaRoles);

        return userDet;
    }

}
```

Class where I have the repository of User class

**UserRepository**

```
package com.sample.negocio.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.sample.modelo.Users;
/**
 * Interfaz para definir las operaciones de bbdd relacionadas con User 
 * @author vcanizar
 *
 */
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String>{

    /**
     * Definición de método para buscar los Users por su ID
     * @param idUser
     * @return
     */

        public Users findByIdUser(String idUser);

        public Users findByEmail(String email);


}
```

The controller

**UserController**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.sample.controller;

import java.util.List;


import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sample.modelo.Users;
import com.sample.negocio.services.UserService;

/**
 * @author vcanizar
 *
 */
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") 
@RequestMapping("/postgresApp")
public class UserController {

    @Resource 
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/userList")
    public List<Users> getUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();

    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/createUser")
    public void createUser(@RequestBody Users user) {
        userService.create(user);

    }
    @PutMapping(value = "/updateUser")
    public void updateUser(@RequestBody Users user) {
         userService.update(user);

    }
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/deleteUserById")
    public void deleteUser(@RequestBody Users user) {
         userService.delete(user);

    }


}
```

User class and entities

**Users.java**

```
package com.sample.modelo;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

/**
 * Clase que representa la tabla Employee
 * 
 * @author vcanizar
 * @Id: Generamos el ID
 * @OnetoOne: generamos un Primary key compartido entre la tabla Employee y
 *            User(Teniendo User el Id principal)
 *
 */
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    // iduser
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String idUser;
    // Relacion con employee
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Employee employee;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String rol;
    /*@AllArgsConstructor
    public enum language {
        FRENCH("FRENCH"), ENGLISH("ENGLISH"), SPANISH("SPANISH");

        private String language;
    }*/


    public Users() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your client secret is encoded.

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
            .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType)
            .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
            .resourceIds(resourceIds);
}
```

Comment: But I don´t have a client in my application